# Repeated Footnotes Not Appearing in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have repeated footnotes in my document, however in the bibliography it only references the first instance of the footnote despite having different numbers.
I want it so that the repeated use of references appear in my bibliography. I am using biblatex inorder to manage my references.
My code looks something like this:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=verbose-ibid, sorting=none]{biblatex}
    \bibliography{example}
    \begin{document}
        Here is sometext.\footcite{ref1}
        Some more text.\footcite{ref2}
        Even more text.\footcite{ref1}
        \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

Rendered Document:
[image: Rendered Document]

[image: Bibliography]

My desire is that citation 3 would appear also in the bibliography.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Change `citestyle` to just `style`.

Comment: I get an error saying: Style 'style' not found.

Comment: Ah sorry, I have just realised what you meant. Please excuse my ignorance! It works fantastic.

Comment: @Johannes_B Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @moewe OP posted an answer. Nothing to do for me here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Johannes_B for the solution. In order to solve this the code needs to be changed from:

```
    \usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
```

to:

```
    \usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
```